# extend jqueryui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

How can I take use of the autocomplete functions to match the following requirements?

- If suggestion matches more than 10 items, it should instead of showing the suggestions, show the number of entries next to the input
- If suggestion matches less than 10 items, it should suggest the autocompletion

I'm new to jquery and jqueryui, but is it right that I can control the "open" event to achieve my requirements? Can anyone help me out here, please? :D

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/wD9RH/

You should use the `callback` option for the `source` parameter.

Read [Overview in Autocomplete documentation page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#overview) to understand how to use it: